# Simple Injector Dependency injection in a IPackage class implementation

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, simple-injector

Is there any way to have dependency injection in a **SimpleInjector.Packaging.IPackage** class implementation? I'm using decorator registration and there’s an overload of the RegisterDecorator available that allows to add a predicate to determine whether a decorator should be applied to a specific service type.

In order to have unit tests the predicate should be configurable trough a parameter. I tried to inject a service in the Package class, but I got **"Packages must have a default constructor.**" exception

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to @Steven's answer (which I agree with), you could create your own `IServicePackage` interface and pass a configuration class to it:

```
public class CompositionRootSettings {

    public string Something { get; set; }

}

public interface IServicePackage
{
    void RegisterServices(Container container, CompositionRootSettings settings);
}

public static void RegisterServicePackages(this Container container, CompositionRootSettings settings)
{
    var packages = from assembly in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
                   from type in assembly.GetTypes()
                    where typeof(IServicePackage).IsAssignableFrom(type)
                    where !type.IsAbstract
                    select (IServicePackage)Activator.CreateInstance(type);

    packages.ToList().ForEach(p => p.RegisterServices(container, settings));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible to let Simple Injector inject dependencies into packages. This is deliberate and the rational behind this is the same as why [the container is locked at first resolve](https://simpleinjector.org/locked). As the link describes, Simple Injector prevents this, because it is dangerous practice, because it can lead to all sorts of hidden problems.

The Packages library is quite simple and it lacks features such as conditional registration. If this is something you require, you will either have to roll your own package implementation (which is actually trivial; just look at the source code), or you register packages explicitly as the following example shows:

```
if (shouldLoadPackage1) new MyPackage1().RegisterPackages(container);
if (shouldLoadPackage2) new MyPackage2().RegisterPackages(container);
if (shouldLoadPackage3) new MyPackage3().RegisterPackages(container);
```